# Android Realm from UI thread

Tags: android, realm

As I have noticed `Realm` database for `Android` does not support passing objects between threads. So my question is - should I run Realm transactions on `UI thread` or should I create some workaround?

Currently I am executing query on separate thread and execute some kind of workaround for the issue that basically replicates `Realm` object:

```
Address.detach(realm.copyToRealm(address));
```

**TL;DR**

Is running `Realm` queries on `UI thread` a performance and `UX` hit?

Comment: You can run query on UI thread. Here link to the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805580/realm-io-and-asynchronous-queries

Comment: Generally running queries on the UI thread is fast enough, but if you are concerned about it you can use the async query API: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries

Answer (score 3):

Running `Realm` queries on UI thread is not really a performance hit unless you query for much data.

Example 1:

- you query for `SomeRealmObject` on **UI** thread;
- you access its fields then via corresponded getter methods;

The query itself should be fast enough. But as you access the returned object(s) Realm performs some magic: if its the first time you access this data, then its getting read from the disk. Otherwise it can already be cached so reading the value should not be a performance problem.

Example 2:

- you query for `SomeRealmObject` on **WORKER** thread;
- you do additional parsing or any other work on this thread;
- you return the `SomeRealmObject` to the main thread. This is completely ok as Realm **does support passing `RealmObject`s between different threads**. (As stated in the official docs: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#threading)
- then you work with this object in the main thread.

In both examples you do some work with the returned object. The main thing to remember is that if your object contains many fields and nested `RealmObject`s (and\or a `RealmList`) and you desperately need to read them all - then you better do it on a worker thread. Option 2 is to *preload* the data into memory and then to work on it. The thing is that Realm does not store data in your java heap (thats why if you try to read variables values while debugging it may read as null even if getters return data). But you can ask it to do so with `Realm.copyFromRealm(yourRealmObject)`. This will return unmanaged `RealmModel` (a `RealmObject` or something else what you feed the method with). And the data will be stored in this new object.

**TL;DR**
Just querying the database in the UI thread may be a performance hit if your query is heavy enough and your DB is large. This includes further data accessing from returned `RealmModel` (RealmObject or RealmResults).

Option 1: do all work in separate threads and pass some parsed data back;

Option 2: query your db and preload all data from separate thread and work with your data in the UI thread as if it was just an `Object` with some fields in it.

Comment: Your post got me confused, so I looked into your provided link: 
"The only limitation is that you cannot randomly pass Realm objects between threads. If you need the same data on another thread you just need to query for that data on the that other thread."

Comment: @HeikoG you can access the DATA from different threads using the same object. But you cannot pass the `Realm` class object between threads